# C# IIS URL Rewrite incorrect for one user

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I implemented a url re-write as per advice on stack and it seemed to be working perfect, as per my web.config code below:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <!--Release / Production only - HTTPS redirect-->
  <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>

    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

This is deployed to a subdomain so we have been redirecting users from http://mysub.mydomain.com to https://mysub.mydomain.com.
One user is having problems on a mobile device, the re-write is sending them to https://www.mysub.mydomain.com

Any ideas on what my be causing this?

Comment: What kind of a mobile device is it?  If it only happens on that single device, I'm guessing the problem is on that client, not your server.

Comment: The users device is a Samsung Galaxy variant, I'm not entirely sure which one. While I tend to agree on the problem being with the client, I'm wondering if there's something I need to do with my re-write rule to tighten it up or specifically ensure the www is omitted. Or alternatively, what's the path I should go down to fix it on the client side I wonder?

Comment: maybe you don't have a DNS entry for www.mysub.mydomain.com  Try pinging mysub.mydomain.com and www.mysub.mydomain.com .  Do they both return the same IP address? Check: http://www.nathanfox.net/blog/8/IIS-7-URL-Rewrite-subdomains-and-host-headers

Comment: They do both return the same IP